# How to print attributes on each separate line with TinyXml

Tags: c++, xml, tinyxml

I'm using TinyXML for creating XML documents in C++.

I would like to see 1 attribute per line in the output documents, like this:

```
<root a="1"
      b="2"
      c="3" />
```

instead of what TinyXML prints by default:

```
<root a="1", b="2", c="3" />
```

Unfortunately, I haven't found any API method that can let me do this.

Without changing the code of TinyXML, is there a way that TinyXML provides to customize the printing so I can see 1 attribute per line?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this by default; you can sub-class TiXmlPrinter to create that behavior:

http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/classTiXmlPrinter.html